# Conditional statment regarding various regex and length of a list in python

Tags: python, regex, list, maxlength

I have following list :

```
  ['E12.2', 'E16.1', 'E15.1']
  ['E10.1', 'I11.2', 'I10.1_27353757']
  ['E16.1', 'E18.1', 'E17.3']
  ['E1.8', 'I12.1_111682336', 'I12.1_111682195']
  ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1','E88.1']
  ['U22.3', 'U22.6_13735517', 'U23.1']
```

and I want to put a condition to filter out the lists that have a) length equal to 3 b) not containing '_' c) not containing alphabet 'U'
I am trying to implement in one line, how do I do that? I have following condition working and I know you can use regex module for matching regex in lists but can I do all the conditions in single line?

```
 if(len(fin_list) == 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way:

```
lists = [['E12.2', 'E16.1', 'E15.1'],
         ['E10.1', 'I11.2', 'I10.1_27353757'],
         ['E16.1', 'E18.1', 'E17.3'],
         ['E1.8', 'I12.1_111682336', 'I12.1_111682195'],
         ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1','E88.1'],
         ['U22.3', 'U22.6_13735517', 'U23.1']]

for lst in lists:
    if len(lst) != 3 and not any('_' in item or 'U' in item for item in lst):
        print(lst)

# Output:
# ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1', 'E88.1']
```

The interesting bit here is the use of `any` over a generator expression. To break it down, this iterates over each `item` in `lst` and applies a test to see if `_` or `U` are in it. That list comprehension results in `True`/`False` for each item in the list. `any` then looks for the first `True`. If it finds one, it immediately returns `True`. If it doesn't find one, it returns `False`.

**EDIT**

Okay, we've clearly moved into the "Just because you can doesn't mean you should," territory, but here's a solution that incorporates the new condition introduced in the comments:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

lists = [['E12.2', 'E16.1', 'E15.1'],
         ['E10.1', 'I11.2', 'I10.1_27353757'],
         ['E16.1', 'E18.1', 'E17.3'],
         ['E1.8', 'I12.1_111682336', 'I12.1_111682195'],
         ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1','E88.1'],
         ['U22.3', 'U22.6_13735517', 'U23.1'],
         ['E7.2', 'E9.5', 'E9.3']]

for lst in lists:
    if (len(lst) != 3 and not any('_' in item or 'U' in item for item in lst) and
            (Counter(match.groups(1) for match in [re.match(r'E(\d+)\.', item) for item in lst] if match is not None)
             .most_common(1) or [(None, 1)])[0][1] == 1):
        print(lst)

# Output:
# ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1', 'E88.1']
```

`Counter` counts things, `re.match` tries to find the numbers after `E`s, and the `.most_common(1) or [(None, 1)]` is to make sure that even if there are no matching elements, we can still index into the result and look for the greatest number of occurrences.

Although the earlier code was okay, this is now terrible code and should be moved out to another function instead. :-)

Comment: For fun, the generator expression can also be replaced with `map(set('U_').intersection, l)`

Comment: hi smarx , alex I have another line that a list as ['E7.2', 'E9.5', 'E9.3'] I want to put another condition where I don't want anything after E to be of same number (in this case it is E9 in both the cases) how do I remove such lines? One thing I can think of is split, if there were a way to include all in same line.

Comment: For this purpose, E9.3 is the same as E9.5, but presumably (from earlier examples), E55.1 is not the same as E56.1. Is that right? (Are you interpreting it as an E followed by a decimal number and ignoring everything after the decimal point?)

Comment: hi smarx I want to drop all the lists that everything common after E be it E9 or E55 so list ['E7.2', 'E9.5', 'E9.3'] will be dropped as well as list ['E7.2', 'E55.5', 'E55.3'], and no just the ones with same number so E55.1 and E56.1 will be different

Comment: I *think* what you want is what I said. E.g. E55.5 and E56.1 both start with "E5", but you're okay with that. You want to only consider them "duplicates" if *all* the digits following the E but preceding the decimal point match.

Comment: Yes and thanks for the above code, I recently switched from shell and awk scripting and I assumed all the conditions can be brought together as that would have been good in awk but clearly I am very new to python.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
ls= [['E12.2', 'E16.1', 'E15.1'],
  ['E10.1', 'I11.2', 'I10.1_27353757'],
  ['E16.1', 'E18.1', 'E17.3'],
  ['E1.8', 'I12.1_111682336', 'I12.1_111682195'],
  ['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1','E88.1'],
  ['U22.3', 'U22.6_13735517', 'U23.1']]

print(list(filter(lambda l : not any(('_' in x or 'U' in x) for x in l),filter(lambda l : len(l)!=3,ls))))
```

result:

```
[['E55.1', 'E57.1', 'E56.1', 'E88.1']]
```

this is complex I admit but meets specs as it is a one-liner:

- outer filter condition is: negation of (underscore or U not contained in any element of the list).
- inner filter condition: list len != 3. Better to start by that to avoid unneccessary processing on elements.

Comment: If you're into this sort of thing, I think list comprehension is more readable. E.g., converting my answer: `[lst for lst in lists if len(lst) != 3 and not any('_' in item or 'U' in item for item in lst)]`.

Comment: that's definitely better, yes. `filter` lost its charm when you had to convert it to `list`. You should add this to _your_ answer. I'll do it.